# including php page after pressing a button

Tags: php

we have four buttons with same name button1 in a for loop . If we press even one button php page has to be loaded for this we use isset function , but the coding is not working properly in the desired manner kindly help...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myButton').click(function() {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container");
    if (this.value == 'collapse') {
  this.value = 'expand';
  $ct.hide("slow");
 $('.myButton').parent().show("slow");
    } else {
  this.value = 'collapse';
  $ct.show("slow");
 $('.myButton').not($(this)).parent().hide("hide");
    }

  });
});
</script>



</head>
<body>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
echo"<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-        color:#E7EFEF;width:84%;  '> 
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
<b>sometext :</b>$b<br>
</p>
<input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton'  name='button1' target='".$i."'       onclick='clickButton(this)'        style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;' >";

echo "<div  class='container'  style='display:none;background:white; '>

  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
<b>sometext :</b>$b<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$c<br>
</p>";
if(isset($_GET['button1']))
{ 
echo"<script>alert('msg1');</script>";
include('function.php'); 
} 
echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

in the above code the alert message is not appearing . this alert should be called on pressing each button respectively...

Comment: You need to reload the page to catch the `$_GET` parameter. Why don't you add the `alert` message to your ` $('.myButton')` click listener? What do you wanne archieve?

Comment: The can be done using ajax calls. You should first learn the difference between [server side and client side scripting](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming). :)

Comment: we want to call the alert message even if i press any of the four buttons which in  the for loop . if any one of the four buttons isset then also function.php shoul be called. all the buttons have same name and are present in for loop

Comment: This is impossible/useless without reloading the page. Is reloading the page a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the fact that php and javascript (or jquery in this occasion) are executed in two completely different moments. The former is executed by the server and the output is sent to the client (browser) who will execute the later. So I don't think your alert will be shown because, unless $_GET["button1] is defined through a get call of the webpage, the code won't even exist for the client.

Comment: yeah i forgot , that was my mistake , so what you suggest, as we have to call function.php if we press any of the four buttons . The function.php should be called only after we press any of the button kindly suggest what to do now.

Comment: You have to go with ajax in that case. Pretty much JavaScript will open a new connection with the server and the answer to that connection is handle by JavaScript and you can output it in your already loaded webpage. There are plwnity of examples. And jquery has its own methods to help you do the derty job. Just make sure you understand what is being executed in what  ... Remember if you want to read from get you have to send it: myoage.com/myfunction.php?myvariable=something.